# Merge two arrays in Go... container assign error

Tags: arrays, sorting, merge, go, mergesort

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my code all this morning but couldn't. It says it cannot assign containers. Please check this go play ground http://play.golang.org/p/RQmmi7nJAK

And the problematic code is below.

```
 func My_Merge(container []int, first_index int, mid_index int, last_index int) {
      left_array := make([]int, mid_index-first_index+1)
      right_array := make([]int, last_index-mid_index)
      temp_i := 0
      temp_j := 0

      for i := first_index; i < mid_index; i++ {
           left_array[temp_i] = container[i]
           temp_i++
      }

      for j := mid_index; j < last_index+1; j++ {
           right_array[temp_j] = container[j]
           temp_j++
      }

      i := 0
      j := 0

      for elem := first_index; elem < len(container); elem++ {
           if left_array[i] <= right_array[j] {
                container[elem] = left_array[i]
                i++
                if i == len(left_array) {
                     container[elem+1:last_index] = right_array[j:]
                     break              
                }           
           } else {
                container[elem] = right_array[j]
                j++
                if j == len(right_array) {
                     container[elem+1:last_index] = left_array[i:]
                     break              
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

I am getting the errors in the line container[elem+1:last_index] = right_array[j:].
Even if I delete the whole block, I am getting errors. Could anybody help me on this? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign to a slice expression in Go. You need to use copy:

```
copy(container[elem+1:last_index], right_array[j:])
```

But apparently there are other problems too, since when I change that in the playground I get an index out of range error.